# VueJS - Correct order of Vuex mutations and Vue-Router redirects?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vuex, vue-router

I am trying to figure out whether the order of Vuex mutations and VueRouter redirects matter in my use-case.

I have two actions; `logout` and `whoami`:

1. We're at route `/app`. Which is protected via a `middleware` to only be accessible when logged in and it uses the `state.user` object in the `template`.
2. User triggers the `logout` `action`.
3. `logout` dispatches `whoami` after posting to `/logout`.
4. `whoami` commits the user's info (to `null`)
5. `login` redirects to `/`.

The method:

```
logout({ dispatch }) {
    Axios.post('logout').then(response => {
        dispatch('whoami').then(() => {
            router.replace('/').catch(err => {})
        })
    }).catch(error => {
        dispatch('whoami').then(() => {
            router.replace('/').catch(err => {})
        })
    })
},
```

Because the user's data would "disappear" (become `null`) for a quick second the VueApp would error because the user's data is being displayed in the `/app` route (`user.name` is now undefined because `user` is now `null` because of the `mutation`).
Then the app redirects to `/` which has all of it's use of the `user` objective wrapped in `if-statements` that check whether the user is logged in.

So as a fix I thought, why not move the redirect to the `whoami` method (optionally):

```
whoami({ commit }, redirect=null) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Axios.post('whoami').then(response => {
            if (response.data.id !== null) {
                commit('login', response.data)
            } else {
                commit('logout')
            }

            if (redirect !== null) {
                console.log(redirect.replace === true);
                if (redirect.replace === true) {
                    router.replace(redirect.to)
                } else {
                    router.push(redirect.to).catch(err => {})
                }
            }

            resolve(response)
        }).catch(error => {
            reject(error)
        })
    })
},
```

But here is the weird part. In my new `whoami` method the redirect **also** comes **after** the `commit`. Yet no similar error appeared.

**Why is this?** Is this because vue's 'reactive' code triggers too slowly? Can I depend on this behaviour?

Comment: Maybe the reason is that the redirect and the commit are too fast, finished in one tick, so your app redirect before Vue reactive.

Comment: @Yan Yes, This is was I was also thinking, but if it is simply because it is to fast. will this consistantly be the case? Can I depend on it or not?

Comment: I do not think it is a good idea to depend on anything which happens asynchronously ... Mutations are synchronous - but route changing is not (because of the possible navigation guards).

Comment: Quite agree. You'd better use v-if to avoid errors caused by undefined user's info.